# How To Broadcast Live TV

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, tv

How can i Broad Cast Live TV  on Windows Vista system?

Reason is i am asking i just want to broadcast festival in my home to broadcast to all my friends . They just use that client or website with ( authentication ) they can see the live.

I would like broadcast live from here to all my friends in all over the world. I thought of doing video chat its so slow for 2 users itself. So i would like to use Broad cast TV Option

Please give me some idea

Comment: Do you mean you want to stream your TV signal? And where do you want to stream to?

Comment: Yes .. Stream TV.. and Some one can watch that Stream Tv from using that client broadcast software .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadcasting over the Internet is a scary thing to do on your own.  A single low-quality stream will be 128kbps for each user, and anything approaching a reasonable quality will be at least 256 kbps.  Even high-speed connections like FiOS (or your local fiber-based ISP) would start to falter at having 3 users connected.

There are commercial services, some free, some not, that handle streaming live video very well.  If you want to broadcast on your own to your friends, a service like [UStream](http://www.ustream.tv/) or [Justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv/) will work great; for a situation where you want to chat amongst your friends, [Stickam](http://www.stickam.com/) is a great service.

A bonus for all three services is that they use Flash to serve the video -- your friends won't have to install any special streaming software to watch.  This is a definite plus since most dedicated streaming software is either very poor quality, filled with spyware/adware, or both.

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment since it might be illegal in your home country, but using UStream/Justin.tv to stream and using a screen capture program as the source will let you capture video from a TV-tuner card.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream using TCP/IP, you can try [icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) as a streaming server.

Or is streaming using a terrestrial antenna what you want?

Comment: Does Icecast stream video? I can only find audio support mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: From the icecast website: »New features for 2.2.0: Icecast now supports video streaming via theora...«

Comment: What is the bandwidth requirement for Icecast?  Is it still 256kbps/client?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used this software but I think Orb does what you're looking for. http://www.orb.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Slingbox](http://www.slingmedia.com/). Admittedly it doesn't stream from Vista. The way it works is you plug your video source (Cable, aerial....) into it, and you also connect it to your network. Then when you're away from home you use their special software to connect to home and watch the live stream.

It does have some limitations, for instance it only allows 1 connected device to watch the stream. Check out the [FAQ](http://www.slingmedia.com/go/faq) page for more

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
Depends on your upload speed.

Answer (score 0):

I myself mostly use [TVmad](http://www.tvmad.com) because it’s probably the most user-friendly and simple to use.

Of course everyone has their own favorites :)

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: Can you please add more detail.  [Please refer to this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to broadcast it locally, you can do it without Internet connection. You can broadcast analogue signals which can be seen on any Analogue/Digital TV with an antenna and in range. You have to buy a analogue broadcast kit (AV Broadcasters). You can buy that from Amazon. Then just connect it to a video source and you are ready to go.
A cheap broadcaster can broadcast up to few meters and a expensive one can do it for some kilo meters.

Comment: When you broadcast beyond your own location (like a few km), you probably need a license.  At least in the US, if you are broadcasting in the frequency range reserved for commercial broadcasts and using enough power to interfere with neighbors' reception, it's covered by regulations.

Comment: well that is true but if you want to may make a look here http://superuser.com/questions/991214/rooting-an-usb-modem-to-broadcast-own-gsm-network?noredirect=1#comment1366851_991214 . I am trying to broadcast own 3g network, range from 1km to 10 km. currently this is a idea only. we are having discussions that it is legal or not. See if it legal, it will help us a lot.